# How to view function/class docstring without editing the code

Tags: python, sublimetext3, docstring

The popup window with a function's docstring is very useful in the Sublime Anaconda package, however it shows only if I type the function or right click -> Anaconda -> Show Documentation.

When reading someone else's code, I would like to look up what a functions docstring without having to right click or use workaround like deleting and retyping the last character of a function.

[image: Popup Window]

Is there a shortcut I am missing? I would anticipate there exist one to view the popup window.

Comment: FWIW PyCharm has "Quick Documentation" shortcut that if configured does exactly that. You can search the settings of sublimetext for a similar shortcut

Comment: Or you can `help(func)` if you are in a simpler environment with a Python console (e.g. shell). But PyCharm is nicer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you can trigger an action by choosing an item from a menu, you can also bind a key to it (and vice-versa).

To do so, you would open the Sublime console with <kbd>Ctrl+`</kbd> or `View > Show Console` and enter the command `sublime.log_commands(True)` to turn on command logging. Once that's done, execute the command (in this case by choosing the item from the context menu) and see what's logged in the console.

For this command, the output is something like this:

```
command: anaconda_doc {"event": {"x": 344.5, "y": 644.5}}
```

This indicates that the command being executed is `anaconda_doc`; the arguments are the location the mouse was at when you issued the command.

With this in hand, you can use `Preferences > Key Bindings` and bind a key to the command `anaconda_doc` to trigger the same command via a key shortcut.

That said, the documentation for the package is linked from it's [Package Control page](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Anaconda), and that documentation has a section for [how to view doc strings](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/IDE/#get-documentation) that outlines the ways to trigger this, which includes a default key binding:

[image: Image of default binding]

When a package has it's own default key bindings, they're generally visible in it's section of the Preferences menu, which in this case would be `Preferences > Package Settings > Anaconda > Key Bindings - Default`; choosing that will show you how the binding is defined so you can change it (by copying it to your user setting and altering the keys):

```
    {
        "command": "anaconda_doc", "keys": ["ctrl+alt+d"], "context": [
            {"key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.python"}
        ]
    },
```

The default binding ensures that it only triggers in Python source files.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I was looking for.